# Images not loading on IE10, 9 and 8 .load bug

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, image-processing, cross-browser

We are building a website for a client but cant seem to find the bug which causes the images under the slider not to load.

There are some posts going around about the .load function not properly working in IE.

Does anyone have an idea?

http://mbx.web-flight.nl/

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/126000#126000) ... either way, have you confirmed in the element inspector the images are actually not loading?

Comment: JS console says `carouFredSel: No element found for "#undefined".`

Comment: I checked alll the IE versions you listed and the slider img's load. Could you post a pic with the problem.

Comment: According to me the element inspector is loaded. Only its not shown. About your remark. I will change the post once I have the answer. I just find it very hard to describe.

Comment: @cam http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/34/9vtm.jpg/ here you see that one image is missing

Comment: @WesleyMurch I dont think it has anything to do with this problem. this seems more about the slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After allot of searching the bug had to do with the imagesLoaded function which was being used which is part of:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

IE does not seem to play nice with it so I made the carousel to initialize on window’s load event (jQuery(window).load) instead of “imagesLoaded”.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is Internet Explorer Quirks Mode. You must define a page header in such a way that IE will load the site in standards mode.  Switch IE to standards mode manually and you will see the images load.

Try the following on the page to declare DOCTYPE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Or try to Force IE to use the latest render mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Learn more about Quirks mode here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Ultimately the BEST solution is to address the problem at the server level if you have access to do so. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  To learn about configuring web servers to specify document modes.

Comment: I checked this as well but its not the cause of the problem. doctype is set as:

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "">

and meta is added, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see. Does anyone see the same as me.  If not, I wonder if it is related to Quirks mode.[image]

Answer (score 0):

On IE 10 for me works fine, but in the IE 9 and lower not works.

This could be happens because the IE 9 don't have some elements of HTML5.

I think that you put this in your file will woks.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Made a test.

I hope help you.

Link for downloads files

https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/